# Programatically opening URLs in web browser in Python

Tags: python, url, tkinter, hyperlink

I have a tkinter script. I was wondering is there anyway to have is so when you hit a button it takes you to a Web Site

```
from tkinter import *
app = Tk()
app.geometry("250x400")
app.title("Links")

def Link():
    ?

button1 = Button(app, text = "To a web site.", command = Link)
button1.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's a [module for that](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html).

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open("http://xkcd.com/353/")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **webbrowser** module to open the `URL`. The documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html

```
# You can use open 
from webbrowser import open
def link():
    open('https://www.youtube.com/')
# You can use open_new_tab
from webbrowser import open_new_tab
def link():
    open_new_tab('https://www.youtube.com/')
```